# Как обновить класс уже существующей entity из консоли?

Tags: symfony2, symfony

Здравствуйте.

Требуется возможность динамически обновлять класс существующих сущностей.

Пока нашел только

`doctrine:generate:entity` - 
Создание новой сущности. При попытке ввода уже существующего класса выдает ошибку

`doctrine:generate:entity` - 
Обновляет сущности в соответствии с базой данных.

Мне же нужно иметь возможность изменять сущности непосредственно из консоли.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать? Может есть какой то бандл?

Comment: `doctrine:generate:entities` - Обновляет сущности в соответствии с базой данных.

Так правильнее.

Comment: Конкретного решения задачи у меня нет. Ну я думаю вам нужно смотреть в сторону компанента "Console". Вот ссылка http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html

Comment: В каком смысле "изменять сущности"? Что конкретно требуется делать и какого рода команду Вы хотите?

Comment: конкретно требуется возможность динамически обновлять класс существующих сущностей (именно php файл). Команды, которые делают подобные задачи, но несколько иначе я привел в вопросе.